# Node.js: get the original string or number from 'this' in the function call

Tags: object, this

When I wrote the codes as the below, I found that javascript will automatically convert the number or string caller (like 1 or 'str' in the codes) to object. And this perform will impact my code to compare the 'this' and the argument 'expectedValue'.

So my questions are:

1. how can I convert 'this' back to original number or string?
2. if cannot find a way to convert back, how can I check 'this' and 'expectedValue' are equal?

```js
var mustEqual = function (expectedValue) {
  console.log("typeof this:"+(typeof this));
  console.log("typeof expectedValue:"+(typeof expectedValue));
  console.log("is equal: "+(this === expectedValue));
}

Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, "mustEqual", {
    value: mustEqual, enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty( Number.prototype, "mustEqual", {
    value: mustEqual, enumerable: false});


if (require.main === module) {
  (1).mustEqual(1);
  ('str').mustEqual('str');
}
```

The output result:

```
typeof this: object
typeof expectedValue: number
is equal: false
typeof this: object
typeof expectedValue: string
is equal: false
```